# Keyboard Select style- side border

Tags: feature-request, design

I'm not a big fan of the big box shadow that is applied on keyboard navigation. I would suggest that we did a left-side border that stands out instead of shadowing over the content.

My proposal would be something like this (stolen from bootstrap)

```
.keyboard-selected {
    box-shadow: inset 7px 0px 0px -4px #2E83B6
}
```

Before:
[image: before]
After:
[image]

On the list page:

Before:
[image: list before]

After: 
[image: list after]

Let me know if anyone has any other suggestions for this, or if they think its a good idea.

Comment: Agreed, the shadow effect surely is pretty ugly.